# multi ajax request and security

Tags: ajax

I have multi ajax requests on my site , when a user want to get for exemple the new notifications, ajax send the request with a code(MD5) and php receive it, the session code will change to an other MD5 crypting, but if the user click on other button to get another things, he can't get any thing because the MD5 code has been changed in the previous request. any reply ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Common Security Mechanism for this,

there are so many sites including social networking sites without md5 and etc....

use http header for secure transmission ans POST methods and etc.